# Don't wait when calling Sub Orchestrator - Azure Durable Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Suppose I'm in a Durable Function and I wish to call a suborchestrator function like so:

```
context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("FunctionName","InstanceId",Object);
```

Right now, even if I don't put `await` in front of the call, the Durable Function will wait until this the sub-orchestrator is complete. Is there any way for me to avoid this? I just want to call the function and forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite forget about tasks, but you don't need to wait for them before moving on, for example

```
public class TaskRunner
{
    private List<IAsyncAction> taskList;
    private AsyncActionCompletedHandler handleThreadComplete;
    public TaskRunner()
    {
        taskList = new List<IAsyncAction>();
        handleThreadComplete = new AsyncActionCompletedHandler(HandleThread);
    }

    public void RunTasks()
    {
        IAsyncAction t1 = Task.Run(() => LongTask(3000)).AsAsyncAction();
        t1.Completed = handleThreadComplete;
        taskList.Add(t1);
        Console.WriteLine("Started Task 1");
        IAsyncAction t2 = Task.Run(() => LongTask(2000)).AsAsyncAction();
        t2.Completed = handleThreadComplete;
        taskList.Add(t2);
        Console.WriteLine("Started Task 2");

        // Start a task and forget about it
        Task.Run(() => LongTask(1000)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Started Task 3 - Fire and Forget");
    }

    public int TaskCount
    {
        get
        {
            return taskList.Count;
        }
    }
    private void HandleThread(IAsyncAction asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
    {
        taskList.Remove(asyncInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Task Complete");
    }
    private async Task LongTask(int waitFor)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitFor);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello after " + waitFor);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TaskRunner tr = new TaskRunner();
        tr.RunTasks();
        while(tr.TaskCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running " + tr.TaskCount + " tasks");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks Complete");

    }
}
```

This will allow you to move on, however you need to keep a reference to the tasks otherwise they will be terminated.

Comment: Is there any way for me to finish the method that called the tasks if the task itself hasn't completed?

Comment: What you are looking for is `Task.Run(() => LongTask(1000)).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Is your answer working in Durable Functions?
The question is asking about "Durable Sub Orchestrator", you are talking about subfunctions.